# AWS getobject + set premission while saving

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

I am working on `AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine` with `AWS PHP SDK V2.8` and `cakephp V2.3`. I am trying to download the object from `AWS S3` to my AWS Server. It is working fine just a issue is How can I set permission `644` to `777` of the file.

Here is my code.

```
        $saveAs = "/var/www/html/app/webroot/files/image/" . $result[$type][0]['id'] . "/" . $result[$type][0]['attachment'];
        $key = "files/image/" . $result[$type][0]['id'] . "/" . $result[$type][0]['attachment'];
        $result = $this->Amazon->S3->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => 'mytest.sample',
            // 'Key' => 'avtar-auth_test_latest5.png',
            'Key' => $key,
            'version' => 'latest',
            'SaveAs' => $saveAs
        ));
```

I also tried

```
   $saveAs = "/var/www/html/app/webroot/files/image/" . $result[$type][0]['id'] . "/" . $result[$type][0]['attachment'];
    $key = "files/image/" . $result[$type][0]['id'] . "/" . $result[$type][0]['attachment'];
    $result = $this->Amazon->S3->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'mytest.sample',
        // 'Key' => 'avtar-auth_test_latest5.png',
        'Key' => $key,
        'version' => 'latest',
        'SaveAs' => chmod($saveAs,'0777')
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of executing the chmod function and passing the result of that into the getObject function, modify the file permissions after the file has been saved using a separate statement:

```
$saveAs = "/var/www/html/app/webroot/files/image/" . $result[$type][0]['id'] . "/" . $result[$type][0]['attachment'];
$key = "files/image/" . $result[$type][0]['id'] . "/" . $result[$type][0]['attachment'];
$result = $this->Amazon->S3->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'mytest.sample',
    // 'Key' => 'avtar-auth_test_latest5.png',
    'Key' => $key,
    'version' => 'latest',
    'SaveAs' => $saveAs
));

chmod($saveAs,0777);
```

Comment: its not working. Don't why but whenever I used that my file permission set to `411` instead of `777`

Comment: What a silly mistake done by me :). anyway you should change `chmod($saveAs,'0777');` to `chmod($saveAs,0777);`